Can you make JS sleep without using async?
I am trying to move an object at the same time (for example moving diagonally by pressing two buttons) with vanilla JS with HTML and CSS and I'm running into problems because my async function does not run at the same time as another function I want to run at the same time.
Here is an example of what I was trying to achieve:
const sleep = (delayInms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInms));
};
async function delay(x) {
    await sleep(x);
}

async function FunctionA() {
     i=0; 
    
    
     while (i < 50) {
        await sleep(10)
        console.log("A")
        i++
     }
}

function FunctionB() {
     console.log("B")
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        var key = event.key.toLowerCase();
        if (key == "w") { 
            FunctionA();
        }
        if (key == "a) { 
            FunctionB();
        }

       

    });
});

Pressing "w" and "a" in quick succession would restart Function A for some reason. I have also tried using .then() but that simply made the while loop never stop.

Two functions don't run "at the same time" in JavaScript.

You have to use another thread. Read about workers

Ignore Konrad. Instead of solving the problem you think you have (need to run 2 things at the same time), try to figure out why you want this in the first place. There's probably a better way to solve this.

Please describe the behaviour you want to achieve -- which output with which keypresses and in which order?

Huge +1 to @Evert. Forget about figuring out how to get your desired solution to work as you expect, what’s the original problem you’re trying to solve that made you arrive at this? See XY problem. Start asking your question over without any functions at all and just include what you want to happen (not how you want it to happen). You’ve alluded to it with “I’m trying something” - what’s the something?

I'm trying to move objects in html with js using those button functions, which is why it's important I need the function not to restart

So maybe you want to just declare the i variable outside the function so it doesn't go back to 0 ?

@Evert the i variable isn't declared at all, so it's already global.

fair but it is set to 0 which is (i assume) the problem?

If you want a function not to be called while it is still in an awaiting state, then keep track of this state with a boolean variable, for instance isReady, which would indicate with true if the function is allowed to be called, and false if it has been called, but could still be resumed after an await.
When you call the function the first time, set this isReady to false, and only set it back to true when the promise returned by that call has resolved.


const sleep = (delayInms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInms));
};

async function FunctionA() {
    let i=0; // Don't have variable declared as global implicitly    
    while (i < 50) {
        await sleep(10)
        console.log("A", i)
        i++
    }
}

function FunctionB() {
    console.log("B")
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    'use strict';
    let isReady = true;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        var key = event.key.toLowerCase();
        if (key == "w" && isReady) { 
            isReady = false;
            FunctionA().then(() => isReady = true);
        }
        if (key == "a") {
            FunctionB()
        }
    });
});
Press w or a...




That didn't work for some reason, pressing the two buttons at the same time sent my object to the sky.

"object to the sky"? What are you referring to? Which object in your question?

I'm trying to move an html object with those two buttons. My pseudo code doesn't say that so that might be the issue

I have included a runnable snippet in my answer which illustrates that FunctionA does not restart, and "B" can be printed while that async loop is still printing "A" (I added the value of i in the output). Was this not what you wanted?

Yes that works, sorry for the confusion. Thanks very much
